# DataType annotation on a list of DateTime objects (ASP.NET MVC/Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is there some way to use the DataType annotation on a list (IEnumerable) of objects, so that when I use DisplayFor in my template it will format the date correctly?

model:

```
public class CallOverview
{

    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = @"{0:dddd dd MMMM yyyy}")]
    public IEnumerable<DateTime> Days { get; set; }

}
```

view:

```
@foreach (var day in Model.Days)
{

    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => day)</p>

}
```

output:

```
31/07/2012 00:00:00
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The answer is it can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason you are seeing this behavior is because you are applying the DataType attribute to the enumeration, not to its individual values. Something like this should work though:

model:

```
public class CallOverview
{
    public IEnumerable<DateTimeWrapper> Days { get; set; }

    public class DateTimeWrapper
    {
        [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = @"{0:dddd dd MMMM yyyy}")]
        public DateTime Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

view:

```
@foreach (var day in Model.Days)
{
    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(m => day.Value)</p>    
}
```

Comment: That would work, but its a little verbose. Would be nice to be able to do something like [DataTypeEnumerable(DataType.Date)]

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you are trying to do.  You need to introduce a new Type to persist the collection via EF.

See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43773647/1742393

```
public class CallOverview
{

    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = @"{0:dddd dd MMMM yyyy}")]
    public PersistableDateTimeCollection<DateTime> Days { get; set; }

}
```